# Cannot Export Crystal Reports .NET version 13

Tags: .net, pdf, export, crystal-reports-export

I have an asp.net 4.0 application running with CR.NET version 13.

When i host it on a w2k3 R2 server running IIS 6 when trying to export the report to pdf on the report viewer i got this error (it tried to download to the browser but then i saw this message popping up):

"Adobe Reader could not open 'xxx.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)"

When I tried to export to Excel or Word format I got a blank document opened.

I have no such error and problem when hosting it on w2k8 server running IIS 7.

Comment: Have you tried moving this file to another computer and try to open it?  My guess the file is indeed incorrect.  Why you are still running IIS 6 on a w2k3 R2 box worries me.

Comment: i couldn't find the pdf file on the server or client machine. I don't think we can upgrade IIS to v7 on a w2k3 R2 box. The version of the IIS is tied to the OS.